# Problems when changing textField to textView?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textview, textfield

I had a viewController with a few textFields. Then after a while, I found out that there really is no way of making textFields into multi-lines (stupid as hell, if you ask me!).

So I changed all of the textFields to textViews, so that the user would have the ability to write several lines. Now, before I had a lot of code combined to these textFields, because of the complexity of getting the textField to move up and down according to keyboardSize and so on.

Wierd thing is, that I thought I could just change all the words 'textField'to textView - and then the keyboard would behave the same way. I can't. Here's my code (changed to try and fit my new textViews instead of the old textFields) :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardY = self.view.frame.height - keyboardSize.height
    let editingTextFieldY:CGFloat! = self.activeTextView.frame.origin.y

    if self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0 {
    // Checking if the textfield is really being hidden:
    if editingTextFieldY > keyboardY - 60 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y - (editingTextFieldY - (keyboardY - 60)), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)
} } }

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

The app compiles fine, but when I press any textView to enter input, istead of the keyboard popping up, the app crashes, and I get: 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'.

This appears on the line 'let keyboardSize = ...'

Can anyone see my error? Or tell me another way to move the view according to the keyboard - when working with textViews and not textFields?

And on another note... Can anyone explain to me, why there even exist both a 'textField' and a 'textView'?? Why in God's name, have apple not just put these to things together to one? ..

Thanks upfront! :)

Comment: I don't know why you change `self.view` 's frame.     `self.view` is a view controller's content view.

Answer (score 2):

To use pod [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

While developing iOS apps, we often run into issues where the iPhone keyboard slides up and covers the UITextField/UITextView.

`IQKeyboardManager` allows you to prevent this issue of keyboard sliding up and covering `UITextField/UITextView` without needing you to write any code or make any additional setup. To use `IQKeyboardManager` you simply need to add source files to your project.